# Reuse const object in react

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Say I would want to have the same codeblock in an object, with an addition:

```
const styles = {
  styleA: `
    background-color: red;
    color: silver;
  `,
  styleB: `
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
  `,
  styleC: `
    background-color: red;
    color: silver;
    font-size: 16px;
  `
};
```

As you can see, styleA and styleC are similar, exept for the fontsize addition to styleC. How can I rewrite this with react (es6) so that

`styleA = styleC + 'font-size: 16px';` ?

Or is there a better way of doing this altogether?

Comment: Extract `styleA` from the object to a separate const?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have something like this.

```
const createStyle = (bgColor, color, fontSize) => {

  return (
    `
    background-color: ${bgColor};
    color: ${color};
    ${fontSize ? `font-size: ${fontSize}` : null}; //if there is fontSize, return it
    `
  );
}
```

thus:

```
const styles = {
  styleA: createStyle('red', 'silver'),
  styleB: createStyle('red', 'silver', '16px')
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using this solution.

Comment: Good luck @Peter

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`css` helper](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#css) from `styled-components` to help create styles and mixins from other readymade components.

For example, in your case:

```
const styleA = css`
  background-color: red;
  color: silver;
`;

const styleB = css`
  background-color: yellow;
`;

const styles = {
  styleC: css`
    ${styleA}
    ${styleB}
    font-size: 32px;
  `
};

const MainHeading = styled.h2`
  ${styles.styleC}
`;
```

Comment: Thank you, especially for mentioning the css helper :)